# CSS table header sticky to parent of parent

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have a HTML structure and I have to make a table header sticky to the `main-1`, but I am not capable of making a working demo. (I tried it with more rows.)
HTML: on CodePen: https://codepen.io/jokemail/pen/VwBvNBv

```css
    
    #printGridHeader
    {
        position: sticky;
        top: 6.5em;
        z-index:202;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    #printGridTable.th
    {
        position: sticky;
        top: 6.5em;
        z-index:202;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<div id="main-1" class="bootstrap">
      <form id="frmSearch_1" method="post">
        <div id="printGridHeader" style="text-align:right;margin:20px 0px;">
          This also have to be sticky and already is
        </div>
        <div id="tableDiv" style="overflow-x:auto;">
          
          <table class="table table-hover" id="printGridTable" style="overflow-x:auto;width:100%;">
            <thead>
              <tr id="printGridTable_head">
                <th scope="col" width="40px">Nr.</th>
                <th scope="col" width="40px">Nr.</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try putting `position: relative` to `#main-1` element and `top: 0;` to `sticky` element.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working

Comment: you alson need to delete `#printGridTable.th` entirely. you do not need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove style `style="overflow-x:auto;"` from **"tableDiv"** Div
2. In your CSS, th is not class. So it would be `#printGridTable th`

Full code below

```css
    #printGridHeader
    {
        position: sticky;
        top: 6.5em;
        z-index:202;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    #printGridTable th
    {
        position: sticky;
        top: 10px;
        z-index:202;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<div id="main-1" class="bootstrap">
      <form id="frmSearch_1" method="post">
        <div id="printGridHeader" style="text-align:right;margin:20px 0px;">
          This also have to be sticky and already is
        </div>
        <div id="tableDiv">
          
          <table class="table table-hover" id="printGridTable" style="overflow-x:auto;width:100%;">
            <thead>
              <tr id="printGridTable_head">
                <th scope="col" width="40px">Nr.</th>
                <th scope="col" width="40px">Data</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-row">
                  <td width="40px">1.</td>
                  <td>126</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok, this is working, but I cannot remove the overflow attribute, as wide tables tend to overlow, so I need the scrollbar. Do you have an idea for this?

Comment: You have style="overflow-x:auto on Table. You don't need to set it on its parent Div

Comment: But it is not working. If I remove the overflow from the div, the table flows out of all of its parents. I have some content on both sides of main-1 div.

Comment: This is totally different issue. If you keep overflow here, it still flows out of all of its parents.

Comment: Do you have idea how to keep overflow-x auto besides the sticky-ness? @Anwar Hossen